# Android device issue

Tags: android

My question is related to android device problem.

We have an android device in our office:
Samsung Galaxy Note 2 - GN7100 (Android version 4.1.2)

We use this devices for android development & testing purpose. But currently the device is creating some problem related to Android Life Cycle. For e.g. in the onCreate() method, we've downloaded data from backend, and now if we rotate the device onCreate() will call again, but we restricted calling onCreate() on device rotation by adding the following line into the  tag:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|keyboardHidden"
```

It was working fine but suddenly this trick isn't working, i.e. the device calling the onCreate() method. Then I do factory reset, but the problem still exist.

My ques is: if this is device issue, then how can we correct it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: onCreate() is called when the activity is created... so if your activity was destroyed for some other reason other than a configuration change, it will be called again... but, you should add screenSize to your list as @archon92 points out since rotating the device will cause a screen size change.

Comment: Thanks. After adding "screenSize" it's working fine. @illegal Argument, from ur given link I got the following lines, which are useful:

" ... to prevent runtime restarts due to orientation change when developing for API level 13 or higher ... must include the "screenSize" value in addition to the "orientation" value. That is, must decalare android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize". However, if application targets API level 12 or lower, then  activity always handles this configuration change itself."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

and format your code.This worked for me

```
//Define Below in you Manifest file.
           <activity
                  android:name="yourname"
                  android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            </activity>

//Define Below in your activity. 

         @Override
            public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

              super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

              if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                  //your code
              } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            //your code

              }
            }
```